# Taylor approximation of inverse square root

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

Given the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+mx+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}$ I am reading that $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$, the inverse square root, can be computed with first order Taylor approximation and take $g(x) = 1 - \frac{m}{2}x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$. So given, $f'(x) = \frac{m+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}{2\sqrt{1+mx+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}}$, I started with the first order Taylor approximation of $f(x)\approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ in point $a$ but I do not know how to continue. Could you please give some help?

Comment: Is $f(a)\ne 0$?

Comment: Hint: use the Taylor approximation of $\phi(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}$

Comment: @Gribouillis do you mean something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729705/approximation-to-the-square-root?rq=1)?

Comment: No, there is only one variable here.

Comment: @Bernard i am still trying to catch your point....

Comment: To  come down to a situation of type $1+mx$, you need to have $(a)\ne 0$, that's all.

Comment: Are you thinking of $x \approx 0$ or $x \approx \infty$?  (Big O requires some sort of limit...)

Comment: @EricTowers $x$ is close to zero. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may recall that, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1+u}}=1-\frac{u}2+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as $x \to 0$,
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\underbrace{mx+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}_{u}}}=1-\frac{mx}2+O(x^2).
$$

Comment: Ok i got it! Thanks for you answer!

Comment: @darkmoor You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to write $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}=(1 + m x + O(x^2))^{-1/2}$. Doing the derivative on g(x) (not f(x)) gives you $g'(x)= -m/2 (1 + m x +O(x^2))^{-3/2} +O(x^2)$, so the Taylor expansion (you have a sign error and should read $h(x)=h(a)+h'(a)(x-a)+O(x^2))$ at $a=0$ is:

$g(x)=g(0) + g'(x) (x-0) + O(x^2)= 1 - \frac{m}{2} x + O(x^2)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I made the sign correction. What I didn't catch is, why do you compute Taylor in point 0? Can you give an intuitive explanation?

Comment: @darkmoor : If $x \approx 0$ and the Taylor series expanded around zero has positive radius of convergence (and is, in some way "simple"), then expanding around zero is the way to go.